# Replace strings in data frame columns with integer in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame called 'foo':

```
 foo <- data.frame("row1" = c(1,2,3,4,5), "row2" = c(1,2.01,3,"-","-"))
```

'foo' was uploaded from a different program as a CSV file and has two columns. one is a numerical data type and the other is a factor data type.

```
str(foo)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
$ row1: num  1 2 3 4 5
$ row2: Factor w/ 4 levels "-","1","2.01",..: 2 3 4 1 1
```

Notice there are dashes, e.g. "-" , in foo$row2, which causes this column to be a factor. I want to replace the dashes with zeros, such that data.class(foo$row2) will return 'numerical'. The idea is to replace all dashes in each column so I can run numberical analyses on it with R.

What is the simplest way to do this in R?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: The idea is to replace all dashes in each column so I can run numerical analyses on it with R.

Use `apply` or `sapply` with `sub`

```
 kk<-data.frame(apply(foo,2,function(x) as.numeric(sub("-",0,x))))
> kk
  row1 row2
1    1 1.00
2    2 2.01
3    3 3.00
4    4 0.00
5    5 0.00

> str(kk$row2)
 num [1:5] 1 2.01 3 0 0
```

Or, you can use `sapply`

```
kk<-data.frame(sapply(names(foo),function(x)as.numeric(sub("-",0,foo[,x]))))
```

Update: 
If you want just the second col, you don't need to use `apply`:`foo$row2<- as.numeric(sub("-",0,foo[,2]))`

Comment: Does this apply the string replace function to each column in the data frame? If so, how can I target the second column only? Thx!

Comment: Yes, it does for all columns. If you want just the second col, you don't need to use `apply`:`foo$row2<- as.numeric(sub("-",0,foo[,2]))`

Comment: Instead of calling foo[,2] for the second column index, how can I call it by column name, i.e. foo$row2<- as.numeric(sub("-",0,foo[,foo$row2]))?

Comment: @AME did you even look at the other answers? This is exactly what I posted.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one simple way to do it.  There might be a more elegant way, but this will work:

```
> foo <- data.frame("row1" = c(1,2,3,4,5), "row2" = c(1,2.01,3,"-","-"))
> levels(foo$row2)[levels(foo$row2)=="-"]<-0
> foo$row2<-as.numeric(as.character(foo$row2))
> class(foo$row2)
[1] "numeric"
> foo
  row1 row2
1    1 1.00
2    2 2.01
3    3 3.00
4    4 0.00
5    5 0.00
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `ifelse()` for this:
`foo$row2 <- ifelse(foo$row2 == "-", 0, as.numeric(foo$row2))`

you might also need to as `as.character()` to convert from factor to character

Comment: And an `as.numeric` to convert it to the numeric form OP needs.

Comment: Running this code on the real data set (not the example one shown here) returns #NA Coerced. The real data set that i'm trying to run this function on contains commas, e.g. 1,000. This seems to force an #NA coercion with the command you provided.

Answer (score 1):

How about `gsub`...

```
as.numeric( gsub("-" , 0 , foo[,2] ) )
#[1] 1.00 2.01 3.00 0.00 0.00
```